# Corrupted data with serial connection

Tags: python, arduino, pyserial, teensy

I'm trying to send data between Raspberry Pi and Teensy with serial connection.

Code for teensy :

```
void setup() {
  Serial1.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  Serial1.println("HELLO");
  delay(1000);
}
```

Python code for Raspberry Pi :

```
import serial
import sys
import string

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyAMA0', 9600)
while True :
    try:
        data=ser.readline()
        print(data)
    except:
        print("Unexpected error: {}".format(sys.exc_info()))
        sys.exit()
```

Result :

[image]

Why data seem to be corrupted? The parity bit is not supposed to prevent that?

Comment: no idea. Just a bonus point for the idea to create a gif as screen "video". BTW: You're not using parity in your default  (= 8N1 ) setting

Comment: I tried with 8E1 : no change

Answer (score 0):

Try to insert `ser.flushInput()` and `ser.flushOutput()` after `ser` creation.

Comment: No change with these instructions.

Comment: Do you also flush buffers on another side?

Comment: Yes, I used Serial1.flush()

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to communicate between an Arduino and Python 3 running on my laptop. The Arduino was supposed to receive `0x30`, i.e. an ASCII `0` and reply with ASCII `"Arduino reachable."` (see the code at the end). The Python code was as simple as it gets:

```
import serial, time

ports=['/dev/ttyACM0']
fixture = serial.Serial(port=ports[0],baudrate=9600,timeout=2,stopbits=sm.serial.STOPBITS_ONE,parity=sm.serial.PARITY_EVEN,bytesize=sm.serial.EIGHTBITS)

fixture.write(b'0')
time.sleep(0.1)
if (fixture.inWaiting() > 0):
    dataStr = port.read(fixture.inWaiting())
    print(dataStr)

fixture.close()
```

The Arduino was replying, but the reply didn't make much sense: `'A.V¥n\x0b\x92\x95a,+\x89lY©'`. In the end, I've changed `parity` to `serial.PARITY_NONE` and that worked like a dream.

Also, I suggest the following method of waiting for the data to appear:

```
TIMEOUT = 20
timeoutCounter=0

while fixture.inWaiting() <= 0: # Wait for data to appear.
    time.sleep(0.1)
    timeoutCounter += 1
    if timeoutCounter == TIMEOUT:
        fixture.close()
        raise BaseException('Getting test data from the Arduino timed out.')
```

### Related Arduino code

```
void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
    char cmdChar = '0'; // Which test case to execute. 0 - do nothing.
    // Wait until there is something in the serial port to read.
    if (Serial.available() > 0)
    {
        // Read the incoming serial data.
        cmdChar = Serial.read();
        // Eexecute the chosen test case.
        switch(cmdChar)
        {
            case '0':
                Serial.print("Arduino reachable."); // Send ASCII characters.
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

### Caveat

I'm sorry but I've had to edit this code before posting, and haven't had a chance to re-test it. However, the main solutions to errors like reported in the questions still hold:

1. Wrong parity (probably stop bits also),
2. Insufficient waiting for the data to appear (possibly not the cause of the problem but definitely a bad practice).

Comment: I solved my problem by adding a link between Raspberry Pi ground pin and Teensy ground pin.

Answer (score 0):

I encounter this before when I use. Why don't just use /dev/ttyUSB0? I am using it now it now and have no issue.